# Fixed precision always in js 0.5 -> 0.5000

Tags: javascript, node.js, fractions

I am trying to fix every fraction number up to n decimal place. But in javascript/nodejs it seems not possible to convert `0.5` to `0.5000`. Due to which my test cases which expect `0.5000` fails.

Any idea how can I do this in nodejs/javascript?

Comment: What part of `.toFixed(4)` isn't working?

Comment: Why do you need to test it against`0.5000`  in the test case. Either you use a decimal class to work with real decimal numbers. Or you have floating point numbers, and then `0.50000` does not make any sense anyway. But even if you have a decimal class then why should  `0.50000` be relevant?

Comment: @t.niese
Please have a look at this
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/plus-minus/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

Their check is failing since my js code returns 0.5 and not 0.5000

Comment: @t.niese
in case you want to see what I tried
`function plusMinus(arr) {
var result = [0,0,0];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] > 0){
        result[0] += 1;
    }else if(arr[i] < 0 ){
        result[1] +=1;
    }else{
        result[2] +=1;
    }
}
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    result [i] = (result[i] / arr.length);
}
return result;
}`

Comment: Add relevant code into your question and not as comment. There is neither a decimal number, nor a floating point number or any test case in that code.

Comment: @SureshPrajapati Please edit your question with code not paste it in comments.

Comment: @t.niese the comment is not relevant to question I asked, hence not a part of it. It's just reference to my answer to hackerrank question

Comment: The hackerrank question and my answer in comments can help you understand why I need `0.5000` since some of the testcases failing because of that.

Comment: @SureshPrajapati Also in c and c++ there are no `0.5000` if you see that then it is a string representation, of either a float, or a decimal class. But here is no such thing as `0.5000` as numeric data type, in js, c or c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said `Number.prototype.toFixed()` should work for you. I tried my hands on and this works perfectly.

```js
function plusMinus(arr) {
let length = arr.length;
let o = arr.reduce((acc,cv)=>{
    if(cv > 0){
        acc.pos++;  
     }
    else if(cv<0){
        acc.neg++;
    }
    else{
        acc.zero++;
    }
    return acc;
},{pos:0,neg:0,zero:0});
    console.log((o.pos/length).toFixed(4));
    console.log((o.neg/length).toFixed(4));
    console.log((o.zero/length).toFixed(4));
}
plusMinus([-4,3,-9,0,4,1]);
```

Comment: Can you please check the test cases result for your solution here 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/plus-minus/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

Comment: I don't know why but i submitted with this code and it works :P

Comment: Only part which was required is to print those.
Now it's working for my code too

Comment: @SureshPrajapati It should have thats what I commented earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `number` prototype method `toFixed`

```js
var num = 5.0;
var n = num.toFixed(4);
console.log(n) //output: 5.000
```

Comment: This return a string and not a number

Comment: @SureshPrajapati in js you only have floating point numbers, there is nothing like `0.5000`. If you want to have `0.5000` then you need to use a string (or a decimal class).

Comment: That's what I am searching in js

Comment: @SureshPrajapati but the output that represents `0.5000` has to be always a string. There is no numeric type that represents `0.5000`

Comment: @t.niese is that means number - `0.5000` is not possible in js/nodejs ?
A no, can answer my question, but if it can be done, I am curious to know that how?

Comment: It's not possible. It will always remove the trailing `0` as those have no use to the runtime.  Just like I cannot have an integer that is `00001`

Comment: @SureshPrajapati not as a primitive numeric data type. You can represent it as array, string, two number or what so ever.

Comment: @SureshPrajapati I think the string shouldn't be a problem in your use case.

Comment: @vibhor1997a Can you please try this simple question of hackerrank ?
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/plus-minus/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

This needs an answer to four decimal places always. Hence `0.5000` is required to pass all the test-cases which seems impossible in js/nodejs

Comment: @SureshPrajapati You need to print the answer in the stdout. So, if you use `toFixed` then you can print that into console. That shouldn't be an issue.